# Setting UIToolBar background image

Tags: ios, ios5, uitoolbar

I have an image that I would like to use as the background for a UIToolBar in an iOS 5+ app.  The background image changes according to actions taken on the view.  The image is larger than the UIToolBar, so the image needs to be resized as a reduction rather than increasing the size.

After review of the other questions on here, as well as other research into the issue, the resolution recommended does not work.  The recommendation is as follows:

```
UIImage *topimg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"headerBar-Human.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[_headerBar setBackgroundImage:topimg forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionTop barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I have tried with different values in the UIEdgeInsetsMake call with no luck.  The problem is that the image is not shown at all.  The default blue toolbar background is shown.

If I remove the resizableImageWithCapInsets function the image will show, but only the portion of the image covered by the toolbar rect coordinates.

I have also tried creating a UIImageView, adding the image and adding it to the toolbar, but the results are the same.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to customize a UIToolBar, or UINavigationBat, you have to subclass it.

Comment: As of iOS 5 you do not need to subclass it.  There is a method, backgroundImageForToolbarPosition:barMetrics: opened up by Apple in iOS 5 to allow adding an image as the background.  This is where I am having a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to resize your backgroundImage :

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

I suggest to call this function with your `_headerBar.frame.size` as second parameter.

Comment: I added this as a category to UIImage and it works well.  thanks!